# TF2 keeps crashing when attempting to use a sound mod?

Tags: technical-issues, team-fortress-2, mods

I've recently downloaded a mod that allows 3 of the TF2 character models and voices to be changed.

I've looked up on the wiki with my previous problem of making the voices work wile the models were working just fine.

My problem now is that whenever I activate the code `sv_pure 1` and start a server, my game crashes and I don't know why.

If anyone can help me I'd be very grateful.

Comment: it's because you're activating the code sv_pure 1 with the sound mod

Comment: `sv_pure` is not a client setting.  It's a server setting.  Last I checked, all Valve servers have it set to 1.  Custom servers may or may not, but considering that it's the first defense against wallhacking...

Answer (score 1):

The code "sv_pure 1" makes your server [or game] not accept edited files. These include sound mods, graphical mods etc.

> sv_pure 2 is no custom content at all.
>   sv_pure 1 is custom content allowed if it is whitelisted.

About the whitelist: It checks the pure_server_whitelist.txt file in  server's hl2 directory

See [here](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Pure_Servers) for the page about this on Valve Dev Wiki and [here](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Pure_Servers#Default_pure_server_whitelist.txt_File) for the default whitelist file.

Note: Even if you whitelist it, you still won't be able to join sv_pure 1/2 servers except yours.

Comment: Also be aware that this is a rewrite, SE died while I was sending my answer, the first edition was longer and better.